# URL found in nginx access.log along GET request

Tags: security, nginx, curl, amazon-ec2

I am managing a site hosted on aws ec2 using nginx. To avoid threats continuously monitoring nginx logs ( access.log & error.log). Though many threats are well managed by tweaking nginx.conf, but this specific one I am not even able to figure out how attacker manage to send such request.

**access.log**
`xx.xxx.xx.xxx - - [18/Aug/2021:09:04:13 +0000] "GET http://xxxxxxxxx.com/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1400 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"`

In above case let's say name of my website is  "h ttp://abc-xyz-1234.com", attacker is passing url in path (i.e. http://xxxxxxxxx.com/ ), and nginx  responding with "200". I am still scratching my head how was request made and what was  responded with 1400 of bytes ( response length still much lesser  than website response site for path  "/" ).

As I believe its not possible through browser, I tried to simulate using curl but it wouldn't work.

1. it is considered 2 separate request to curl
   `curl -A Mozilla  h ttp://abc-xyz-1234.com/ http://xxxxxxxxx.com`
2. invalid domain
   `curl  -A Mozilla  h ttp://abc-xyz-1234.comhttp://xxxxxxxxx.com`
3. it will hit host with path /http://xxxxxxxxx.com and get rejected. Attacker is manage to send it without prefix "/" and thats what  trying to simulate
   `curl -A Mozilla  h ttp://abc-xyz-1234.com/http://xxxxxxxxx.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`--request-target`](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#--request-target) for this:

```bash
curl -A Mozilla http://abc-xyz-1234.com --request-target http://xxxxxxxxx.com
```

Comment: Sorry, no idea.